# Table for unpacked quantity of incoming delivery items in SAP EWM

Tags: odata, cds, sap-ewm

Searching for a datebase table in SAP EWM to use in a Fiori dashboard for displaying transport units in inbound logistics. I can find the data in transaction /scwm/tu at the tab delivery items:
[Screenshot /scwm/tu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozdSB.png)

Searching for the unpacked quantity of the assigned delivery item(s). It's like the amount is already bound to a handling unit, where I can also see the unpacked amount in the details, but as it's a PLAN handling unit I can not find the required data in the "normal" hu tables. Does someone know where to look this up?

I did have a look at

- /scwm/tu_sr_act
- /scwm/tu_dlv
- /scwm/huhdr
- /scwm/gmhuitm
- /scwm/ordim_h
- /scwm/whohu
- /scdl/db_hu

Maybe I also just went in the tables with the wrong parameters (mostly docid of the delivery or the huident or hu_guid) ? Been also thinking of /lime/nquan, but could not find any table to map the guids to the /lime/ tables..

Thankful for every idea!